# Generating dynamic arguments C

Tags: c

Assume the following macro:

```
#define print(...) \
    int a[] = {__VA_ARGS__}; \
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){ \
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);\
    }
```

which can be used to print `1,2,3` using this call:

```
int main(){
  print(1,2,3);
  return 0;
}
```

Now what If I want t generate the arguments list dynamically (in a for loop for example) and pass it to `print` without changing the print function? so it would look like this:

```
print(1,2,3,....,n);
```

is this doable in C?

Comment: Please learn to use functions instead of macros in C. Putting code in macros in C is actually a bad practice.

Comment: is there a way to generate dynamic arguments in C at all regardless of Macro? i'm talking about generating arguments, not a function that takes in infinite arguments, i already know thats doable.

Comment: Alway prefer variable length arguments than macros, here you have a nice example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-argument-c/

Comment: Your question is unclear in the sense you have not adequately explained or illustrated what you want to accomplish. However, if you consider a string as a way to represent dynamic arguments, it is possible to implement a string parser to extract the arguments. Without more specifics, it is difficult to advise further.

Comment: ok so without macros, you can generate a list of arguments dynamically then? how?

Answer (score 0):

you can just pass it as an array of dynamically allocated ints, and tell it how big the array is, instead of bunch of separate ints. But you can't really change it dynamically, macros need to be resolved at compile time. Like others suggested it would probably be easier to do this using the functions provided in `stdarg.h` by using a VLA.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not doable.

The number of arguments you pass to the function (or macro) has to be explicitly set at compile time. Just print each number individually.

However, if you know at the time of compiling the code how many arguments this macro will be passed, then it is possible (with some [macro magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic/)).